# Select class in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr class="unique_1">
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td class="status_td"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="unique_2">
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td class="status_td"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="unique_3">
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td class="status_td"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="unique_4">
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td class="status_td"></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Now I want to select `<td class="status_td">` in `<tr class="unique_3">`. The `<tr>`'s unique id is inside a variable.

What I have so far is:

```
$(trClass + '> .status_td').html('Some data');
```

`trClass` contains the unique ID (`.unique_3`)

But this doesn't work, does anyone have an solution for my problem?

Comment: `var trClass = '.unique_3';` presumably?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `'.' + trClass`?

Comment: What is the value of trClass, or what is the value of `console.log(trClass + '> .status_td')`

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svineet/KLcLE/).

You have to add `.` to the start of the `trClass` so that jQuery knows it's a class. And to other people, my fiddle is working without the space!

```
$('.'+trClass + '> .status_td').html('Some data');
```

Comment: "trClass contains the unique ID (.unique_3)" : the point is already there.

Comment: @GuidoVisser: In that case, [something is wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/EaAKB/).

Comment: I have removed the point from the variable and added it like this post. Then it works perfectly. Thank you guys, you made my day! :D

Comment: It's weird indeed. Well anyways thank you guys so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

```
var trClass = "unique_3";

var item = $("." + trClass + " > .status_td");
```

Answer (score -1):

You are appending the `>` to the class name of the `<tr>` you are trying to select which is causing jQuery to search for the selector string `.unique_3> .status_td`. This obviously does not select the proper `td` since a class of 'unique_3>' does not exist in you DOM.

Just remove the child selector and select `$(trClass + ' .status_td')` instead.

Comment: `>` is the child combinator.

Comment: no, it is a selector. and it is unnecessary here since a descendant selector will suffice because none of the other `<td>` elements have classes.

Comment: @Andrew, please [read this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

Comment: It might be unnecessary, but that won't stop it from working. What your first paragraph seems to say is that `.unique_3>` doesn't exist in the DOM - that's wrong. `>` is not part of the class name. And yes, it's actually called a combinator.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. However look at his javascript: `$(trClass + '> .status_td').html('Some data');`. There is no space between the `trClass` string variable and `> .status_td` string, which would output `.unique_3> .status_d`.

Comment: @Andrew: It would! But [it doesn't matter](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/N9qL3/). Spacing usually doesn't. The `>` would need to be escaped to be treated as part of the class name.

Comment: @lante this is jQuery, not CSS. Please read http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: @Andrew: jQuery's selectors are both based on and backwards-compatible with CSS. (It even optimizes to `document.querySelectorAll` when possible.)